# When I add a COM reference to Excel 16.0 object library why I am getting version 15 definitions?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have an app that uses Excel to create some charts. I need to add xlTreemap, which is a new one. In my project I add a COM reference to "Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library." It's version 1.9 and has a file version of 16.0.11929.20562. When I look at what is available in the `XlChartType` enum it's missing the new chart types. If I F12 into the type I get this at the top of the file:

```cs
#region Assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
// C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
#endregion
```

Why is it giving me version 15? As far as I know I have everything installed that I need. Feel like I'm missing something simple, but I don't know what it is. I can open Excel and create a treemap.

I searched my hard drive for all `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` files and it found one in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesX86\Microsoft Office\Office16\DCF` that is actually version 16. I added a reference to that file in my project and everything is working.